# Register global hotkey in managed code

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, hotkeys, managed

How can I register a global hotkey using Mono C# (gtk) so it works on Windows, Linux and Mac?

So far all I know is I have to `P/Invoke` in order to `Register/Unregister` the hotkey, but is there a way to do this in managed code, since I want it to work on any platform?